# react hooks : show loading spinner from child

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new with React and I want to understand hooks.

***Expected result*** : have 2 global functions to show/hide a loading spinner from anywhere in components tree.

***Actual result*** : When I call *showLoader* and *hideLoader* in useEffect of ChildPage, it is looping on the render.

After reading several tutorials and many answers on this site, I would like to understand what's wrong in my code. (I have already tried Redux but I had the same result).

**App.js**

```
const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => (
  <StateContext.Provider value={reducer}>{children}</StateContext.Provider>
);
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);

const loaderReducer = (state = false, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "show_loader":
      return { isFetching: true };
    case "hide_loader":
      return { isFetching: false };
    default:
      throw new Error("Unexpected action");
  }
};

const App = props => {
  const initialState = { isFetching: false };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(loaderReducer, initialState);

  return (
    <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={{ dispatch }}>
      <div className="App">
        {state.isFetching ? (
          <ReactLoading
            className="loader"
            type="cylon"
            color="#4caf50"
            height={64}
            width={64}
          />
        ) : (
          <ChildPage />
        )}
      </div>
    </StateProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**StateContext.js**

```
const StateContext = createContext(null);
export default StateContext;
```

**childPage.js**

```
const ChildPage = props => {
  const { dispatch } = useContext(StateContext);

  const showLoader = useCallback(() => dispatch({ type: "show_loader" }), []);
  const hideLoader = useCallback(() => dispatch({ type: "hide_loader" }), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchExample() {
      showLoader();
      await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json));
      hideLoader();
    }
    fetchExample();
  }, [showLoader, hideLoader]);
  //same thing with [] as second arg

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>hello in ChildPage</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChildPage;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ChildPage got destroyed while loading?

I've read your code.   You used conditional expression to control the UI. That is the very reason you got loop renderings.

How to understand it?

Every time the Effect callback got invoked, `showLoader` is called which leads ChildPage to be unconstructed. After the    fetch promise settled, `hideLoader` is called which leads ChildPage re-constructed and then the Effect callback will be applied.

You set a loop here. :)

Comment: Oh okay I think I understand, but do yo have any solutions ?

Comment: Why do you do fetch every time the ChildPage born? Why not putting this logic outside and providing what ChildPage needs throu props?  Or Pls do not deconstruct it while fetching. Keep it in the tree by setting spinner inside.

Comment: Where should I put this logic ? Because I have a lot of fetch to call

Comment: in the App component.

Comment: even though I have almost 10 different APIs to call ? and I don't have only 1 child

Comment: Don't let your children unconstructed. ~